# Where do all the oracle 11g Qs come from?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It seems like in the last weeks, a lot of low quality questions regarding Oracle 11g are popping up where most users asking them show scriptkiddie understanding of the matter at most.

Here are some examples:

- [Understanding Oracle 11g password hashing algorithms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162693/understanding-oracle-11g-password-hashing-algorithms?s=1|119.8664)
- [Oracle database 11g weird hashed results](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172215/oracle-database-11g-weird-hashed-results?s=2|84.1918)
- [Identify the type of the hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172232/identify-the-type-of-the-hashes?s=5|47.0060)
- [Hash type identification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172510/hash-type-identification?s=7|39.5351)
- [Oracle Sql Injection Reverse Shell](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/oracle-sql-injection-reverse-shell)

Please also note that three of those questions are posted by the same user.

What makes me wonder is: Oracle is not the database management system of choice for newbies (and not even for most other people).

Is there an online security tutorial that uses this dbms and - maybe - encourages users to ask here to get rid of customer support questions?

Comment: I am also curious. It's like a new 'hackme' site just launched or something

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Maybe I am paranoid here, but to me it looks like they could all be from the same person...